# Delta operator in sympy

Tags: math, matrix, sympy, symbolic-math

Is it possible to make a delta operator like this in sympy? Im not really sure how to code it. Should be really eazy if there exists a method.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if SymPy exposes something that could be useful to you. If not, we can create something raw.

Note: the following approach requires a bit of knowledge in Object Oriented Programming and the way SymPy treats things. This is a 5 minutes attempt, and it is not meant to be used in production (as a matter of fact, no test has been done over this code). There are many things that may not work as expected. But, for your case, it might work :)

One possible way is to define a "gradient" class, like this:

```py
class Grad(Expr):
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return other.diff(*self.args)
    def _latex(self, printer):
        # create a latex representation to be visualize in Jupyter Notebook
        return r"\frac{\partial}{%s}" % " ".join([r"\partial %s" % latex(t) for t in self.args])
```

We can create a gradient of something with respect to `x` by writing `gx = Grad(x)`. Once `gx` is multiplied with some other thing, it returns the partial derivative of that thing with respect to `x`.

Then you would define your symbols/functions and matrices like this:

```py
from sympy import *
init_printing()
var("x, y")
N1, N2, N3 = [s(x, y) for s in symbols("N1:4", cls=Function)]
A = Matrix(3, 2, [Grad(x), 0, 0, Grad(y), Grad(x), Grad(y)])
B = Matrix(2, 6, [N1, 0, N2, 0, N3, 0, 0, N1, 0, N2, 0, N3])
display(A, B)
```

[image]

Finally, you multiply the matrices together to obtain the symbolic results:

```py
A * B
```

[image]

Eventually, you might want to create a function:

```py
def delta_operator(x, y, N1, N2, N3):
    A = Matrix(3, 2, [Grad(x), 0, 0, Grad(y), Grad(x), Grad(y)])
    B = Matrix(2, 6, [N1, 0, N2, 0, N3, 0, 0, N1, 0, N2, 0, N3])
    return A * B
```

So, whenever you have to apply that operator, you just execute `delta_operator(x, y, N1, N2, N3)` to obtain a result similar to above.

Comment: Do you know if its possible to make a chain rule version of this? Lets say the N1,N2... Are functions of "xi" and "eta" then the Delta operator would be Matrix([d/dxi * dxi/dx , 0 ],[0 , d/deta * deta/dy],[d/deta * deta/dy , d/dxi * dxi/dx])

Comment: I think its possible, but it would take considerable more time to achieve it...

Comment: Ohh. i was not thinking about a very complicated one. Just one where i can say that my dxi/dx = 5. etc end it would make the calculations from that the correct places.